# Extract only characters from a image opencv or OCR

Tags: python, ocr, tesseract, easyocr

From a group of text like below
[image]

I want to MAKE a BOUNDING BOX on INDIVIDUAL ***CHARACTER***.
However, I am unable to do so.

I've tried to use Easy OCR with following settings but it only recognizes individual words:

```
reader = eo.Reader(['en'],gpu=True)
result = reader.readtext(imgOriginal,y_ths=0.0000000001,x_ths=0.0000000001,paragraph=False)
```

I tried to set psm/oem in tesserocr/pytesserocr but still I wasn't able to get the individual character. Please Help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at [GetComponentImage example](https://github.com/sirfz/tesserocr#getcomponentimages-example) from tesserocr and adapt it:

```
from PIL import Image, ImageOps
from tesserocr import PyTessBaseAPI, RIL

image = ImageOps.grayscale(Image.open('test.png'))).convert('L')
with PyTessBaseAPI(path=tessdata_path, psm=tesserocr.PSM.SPARSE_TEXT) as api:
    api.SetImage(image)
    api.Recognize()
    boxes = api.GetComponentImages(RIL.SYMBOL, True)
    print('Found {} symbol image components.'.format(len(boxes)))
    for i, (im, box, _, _) in enumerate(boxes):
        print("Box[{0}]: x={x}, y={y}, w={w}, h={h}".format(i, **box))
        # display(im)
```

If boxes are not accurate try to use `oem=tesserocr.OEM.TESSERACT_ONLY` with correct trainneddata.

Comment: Any idea for EasyOCR? I would have to change my entire codebase for this.

Comment: or Pytesseract?